# AutoHotKey cannot send mouse click event to inactive Roblox window

Tags: click, mouse, autohotkey, roblox

I'm using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to auto-click in [Roblox](https://www.roblox.com/home), as many of the games are simple clicker games. This works fine if I use the regular [Click](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) or [MouseClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) commands, but that actually moves my mouse cursor into the Roblox window to do the click. I'm looking to be able to send mouse click events to the Roblox window while I do things on the computer on another monitor with the mouse and keyboard.

I believe the [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) command is made for this purpose, and it seems to work for other windows (like text editors), but doesn't seem to perform a click in the Roblox window, even if Roblox is the active/in-focus window. I've also tried using the [PostMessage](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) command, again with no luck.

Here are some code snippets of what I've tried using:

Method 1:

```
; This works, but moves the mouse cursor to the window, which I don't want.
MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY, windowId
Loop, 100
{
    Click, %mouseX%, %mouseY%
    Sleep, 10
}
```

Method 2:

```
; This does not actually perform a click in Roblox.
MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY, windowId
Loop, 100
{
    ControlClick, x%mouseX% y%mouseY%, ahk_id %windowId%
    Sleep, 10
}
```

Method 3:

```
; This does not actually perform a click in Roblox.
MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY, windowId
SetControlDelay -1
Loop, 100
{
    ControlClick, x%mouseX% y%mouseY%, ahk_id %windowId%,,,, NA
    Sleep, 10
}
```

Method 4:

```
; This does not actually perform a click in Roblox.
; Use Window title to match and try sending 2 clicks.
MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY, windowId
SetControlDelay -1
Loop, 100
{
    ControlClick, x%mouseX% y%mouseY%, Roblox, , Left, 2
    Sleep, 10
}
```

Method 5:

```
; This does not actually perform a click in Roblox.
MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY, windowId
Loop, 100
{
    PostClick(mouseX, mouseY, windowId)
    Sleep, 10
}

PostClick(x,y,windowId) 
{
    lParam := x & 0xFFFF | (y & 0xFFFF) << 16
    PostMessage, 0x201, , %lParam%, , ahk_id %windowId% ;WM_LBUTTONDOWN 
    PostMessage, 0x202, , %lParam%, , ahk_id %windowId% ;WM_LBUTTONUP 
}
```

I imagine this problem likely happens with many/any video games, not just Roblox, but I'm not certain. If you have any ideas or suggestions for me to try I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know roblox has some security stuff that prevents you from doing that. You probably have to make a deeper winApi call using [DllCall](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/DllCall.htm).